# Checkbox checked add to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I'm having some issues with my cart. Some jQuery issues and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thing is that I'm trying to make the cart more dynamic, if you check in a checkbox the item gets added to the cart and the total price and discount for that item is shown too.

Just having trouble with the checkbox part.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#cart_listing .quantity').change(function (event) {
        $quan = $(this);
        console.log($quan.parent().next()[0]);
        $quan.parent().next().find('.price').text(function () {
            return $quan.val() * parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'), 10) + ' €';
        });
            var total = 0;
            $('#cart_listing .price').each(function(k, v){
                total += parseFloat($(v).text(), 10); 
            });

            $('#cart_listing .faster').text(function () {
                faster = parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'), 10);
                return $(this).attr('data-val' + ' €');
            });

            var discount_pct = parseInt($("#cart_listing .discount").data("val"), 10);
            var discount = -(total * discount_pct/100);

            $('#cart_listing .discounted').text('-' + -discount + ' €');
            $('#cart_listing #total').text(total + discount + faster + ' €')
    });
});
```

---

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ooh43u6t/

Comment: Which checkbox are you talking about? Your jsfiddle has a bunch of different checkboxes.

Comment: Mostly all of them, but 1 would bring me even closer @hofan41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question correctly, but I think you want to add the value for the checkbox when checked using jQuery.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){ //use this to see if the checkbox is checked or not
         //do something...
     }
});
```

I don't know if you wanted something like this. If not, can you clarify more? Thanks!

Edit:

So, you basically use the same thing, something like this perhaps,

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log($(this).parent('td').siblings('td').html()); // check this, you'll have the item name. (the first td)
    console.log($(this).attr('data-val')); // this will have the value on the "data-val" attribute on your checkbox
}
```

So, now you have the name of the product (1st log) and the price (2nd log).
Now keep in mind that this would work only if the format is going to be consistent, and also instead of doing a generic `input[type=checkbox]`, you might want to give all the product checkboxes a unique class, so it doesn't interfere with other checkboxes you might have. Hope this helps. If not, I'd be happy to answer some more. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking like this, let's say you check the checkbox next to "
1x Basic standby overlay:" then the item gets added to the cart on the right (or on top in the jsfiddle page) and the data-val from the checkbox gets added with the total price. @sulavvr

Comment: @PrinceSamuel Can you check the edit part of the answer? Please let me know, if that's going to help you. Thanks!

Comment: So that code did not work, I updated the jsFiddle. I named the checkbox on "Basic overlay" => class="basic_standby". Could you give your answer in the jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ooh43u6t/1/ @sulavvr

Comment: @PrinceSamuel The code didn't work because you have to bind the click event on the checkbox. `$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ //your code... });` You just wrote the `if` statement. Here is the jsFiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/ooh43u6t/2/ .. Hope that helps.. Thanks!

Comment: @sulvavvr Nothing happend in the jsFiddle you sent, the item does not get added to the cart and the price is still the same.

Comment: @PrinceSamuel Well, I thought you just needed someone to point you in the right direction. Replace the `console.log` with `alert` and run the fiddle and click on the checkbox, to see if the items are being alerted or not. After that, you have to use those values, and append it to the cart. Use jquery's `append` method to append the item names to the cart, and for the total, you have the value, just add it to the total price. Is it clear? I don't want to do the whole adding thing, you wouldn't learn that way. I'd be happy to guide you further if you don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: You want me to keep typing here or is there a way to open up a chat for us to discuss?

Comment: I wont be able to chat right now, you have to type it here. I'll get back to you when I get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Alright you pushed me to the right direction, I made it kind of work. It adds the items to the cart but if you uncheck the box and check it again it adds the item again also the price isn't being added to the total price. http://jsfiddle.net/mpcL2fcr/

Comment: Another guy helped me out with this issue, but I'm having trouble with the quantity and the price. The quanitity doesn't update neither does the price and the total price with the discount. http://jsfiddle.net/e2p51y8j/5/

Comment: @PrinceSamuel Good for you man! Check this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/e2p51y8j/9/ .. I'm doing this because of how your cart is being made. You'll probably get the idea here, now run with it. Obviously there are a lot better ways of doing what you and I are doing. If you still have questions, I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: So how do I integrate the quantity procedure with the discount to add up in the total? http://jsfiddle.net/e2p51y8j/7/ there is a bit of the quantity code. On the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: @PrinceSamuel Did you see how the price were being added? Similarly, get the discount, store it somewhere, for now just get it from the discounted div, split it using the `split` function, get the amount, `var discount = $('.discounted').html().split(' ')[0]`.. doing that will give you -10. And now add it to the cart_total and display it. This is just a quick way to do it.. Hope you understood!

Comment: I didn't understand it @sulavvr

Comment: Check this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/e2p51y8j/13/... look at the comments. It's straight forward.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the quantity function but it's going to hell @sulavvr

Comment: Ok, again, I'll try to push you towards the correct direction. On the input `blur` event, that means when you type in the quantity and click outside the textbox, you get the value typed `$(this).val()`. Then you use, the `parent`, `siblings`, `children` etc. methods on jQuery, to get the value for whatever item quantity was edited. In your case, I think something like this `$(this).parent('td').siblings('td').children('div.price').attr('data-val')` or something.. And you get the price, the quantity and run with it! Thanks!

Comment: I think I should let the code rest, jQuery has never been my language. I don't understand anything so I think I should stop here, I appreciate all the help you have given me tho, I will look more into this when I understand more. @sulavvr

Comment: Keep learning man, don't stop. I don't know if you know javascript or not, so you have to start there, don't jump into jQuery. jQuery just makes your life easier. Use PHP & Ajax for your shopping cart. Keep working on it. Ask questions if you have problems. Very happy to help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not used to writing javascript, jquery or php. I just made templates, HTML and CSS. This is something I just tried out, all I want is to have a working cart so I can keep doing designs :) @sulavvr